# Failure to load Flash video with web browser using html

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to display two Flash videos `tangramore.swf` and `bird.swf` on web browser; however, only `bird.swf` was displayed on the page, the `tangramore.swf` did not show up. They are both stored in the "Files" folder. It was working fine before, but then I deleted the code and retyped it, the problem occurred.****

**HTML5 Code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Adding a Flash Movie</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    swfobject.embedSWF("Files/tangramone.swf", "tangramone", "800", "600", "8.0.0");
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    swfobject.embedSWF("Files/bird.swf", "bird", "400", "300", "8.0.0");
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="bird">
    <p>An animation of a bird taking a shower</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: try removing the script for `bird.swf` - does that makes `tangramone.swf` work? Do you currently get any errors in your browsers Developer Tools Console?

Comment: I tried to delete the script for the bird.swf, But it did not work, I also tried to open the html file on few browsers such as Chrome, Firefox, and Internet Explorer, but the tangramone.swf did not display. When I switched the "tangramone" for "bird" the bird.swf worked, but when I used the "FIles/tangramone.swf" the tangramone.swf video did not run.

Comment: You forgot to answer the second question I asked ... Do you currently get any errors in your browsers Developer Tools Console?

Comment: No, I did not get any errors from my browsers Developer Tools Console

Comment: Have you tried opening the tangramone.swf directly in your browser

Comment: Yes, I did. And it worked.

Comment: In the body part, I added the line of code  <div id="tangramone"><p>blahblahblah</p> </div> at the <body></body> part. And it worked on Chrome and Firefox; however, it did not work on Microsoft Edge